# How-to stop wordpress from saving utf8 non-breaking space characters

Tags: visual-editor, post-editor, html-editor

Anyone have a tip on how to prevent Wordpress from saving utf8 space characters (= hex C2 A0) in DB by replacing with space \x20 ?

Is there a hook that can be used to do a replace before saving to tables?

Background:
`&nbsp;` looks like any other "space" character to the eye in editors (Notepad, Notepad++, Wordpress etc.) but actually hides itself in 2-byte code (`\xc2\xa0`) if you view though a hex editor.

Problem: css word-wrap causes sentence not to wrap as they should as it knows it's a "non-breaking space".

User experience: When someone does copy+paste from another source (website, word document etc.) sometimes the original space is a `&nbsp;` and the user doesn't see or know this as they're not that tech focused as we are.

Anyone has an idea or proposal for solution here?

Thx

Comment: there's a lot more than non-breaking spaces that can end up in pasted content. I would train users to get in the habit of using the paste as plain text button, which will strip all formatting.

Comment: Thx @Milo - it's a great idea. The reason I opted for managing the issue with space is that it's less obvious as you cannot see it even in preview. Most other formatting issues can be previewed.

Comment: @Milo non–breaking space isn't affected by plain text paste (I just tested), it's not formatting per se.

Comment: @Rarst - I just tested and it is.

Comment: Curious. I actually get strange reverse behavior — it stays as special symbol with plain text paste mode active (button pressed), but turns into normal space when it's inactive (button unpressed). Clear formatting button doesn't convert it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both initial creation and updates for the posts pass through `wp_insert_post_data` (among other filters). You can modify `post_content` item in array passed to make the replacement you need, before it proceeds on to be saved in database.

**Update** Code pasted from comments

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'rm_wp_insert_post_data', '99', 2 );
function rm_wp_insert_post_data ( $data , $postarr ) {
   return str_replace("\xc2\xa0", " ", $data); 
}
```

Comment: Thx. I'll try this.

Comment: Thx @Rarst It solved my problem by using this hook.
`add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'rm_wp_insert_post_data', '99', 2 );
function rm_wp_insert_post_data ( $data , $postarr ) {
  return str_replace("\xc2\xa0", " ", $data);
}`

Comment: @MattiasFjalestad Then please mark the answer as solution.